# Config declare module for react-native-config?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have an old project config environment by `react-native-dotenv` just like beblow

```
declare module 'react-native-dotenv' {
  export const APP_ROOT_API: string;
  export const APP_PUBLIC_AVATAR_PATH: string;
  export const APP_ABOUT_URL: string;
  export const APP_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID: string;
  export const APP_ONESIGNAL_PREFIX: string;
  export const APP_TEST_USER_ID: string;
  export const APP_TEST_TOKEN: string;
  export const APP_TEST_REFRESH_TOKEN: string;
  export const CLIENT_ID: string;
  export const CLIENT_SECRET: string;
  export const REDIRECT_URL: string;
  export const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT: string;
  export const TOKEN_ENDPOINT: string;
  export const SCOPES;
  export const ENV;
}
```

But now I want to change the config environment by using `react-native-config`

Could I just change code like this:

```
declare module 'react-native-config' {
  export const APP_ROOT_API: string;
  export const APP_PUBLIC_AVATAR_PATH: string;
  export const APP_ABOUT_URL: string;
  export const APP_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID: string;
  export const APP_ONESIGNAL_PREFIX: string;
  export const APP_TEST_USER_ID: string;
  export const APP_TEST_TOKEN: string;
  export const APP_TEST_REFRESH_TOKEN: string;
  export const CLIENT_ID: string;
  export const CLIENT_SECRET: string;
  export const REDIRECT_URL: string;
  export const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT: string;
  export const TOKEN_ENDPOINT: string;
  export const SCOPES;
  export const ENV;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

native-dotenv`maintainer here.`react-native-config` will take a bit more to setup linking and things. Also are these from .env files?